# MenuItem - CustomControl with Event Handler for IsSubMenuOpen

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF MVVM application, when the (sub-)menu of a MenuItem opens, I want to populate the (sub-)menu.

E.g. there is a MenuItem "Logs". Only when the submenu opens, I want to search for corresponding log files on disk and display their filenames in the SubMenu afterwards.

[Populating submenu dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyfeX.png)

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyMenuItemViewModel}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <local:CustomMenuItemControl/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

MyMenuItemViewModel.cs

```
public class MyMenuItemViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyMenuItemViewModel> Children { get; set; }

    public MyMenuItemViewModel(string item)
    {
        Text = item;
        Children = new ObservableCollection<MyMenuItemViewModel>();
    }
}
```

My application is significantly larger, for illustrative purposes I have removed most of it.
I work with a ViewModel that contains a Text and an ObservableCollection "Children" for SubMenus.
It is displayed with a CustomControl that only displays the text.

However, I am already failing to get a trigger when the SubMenu is opened.

I've already tried adding event handler to HierarchicalDataTemplate and CustomMenuItemControl and
a DependencyProperty to the control and tried binding events in XAML, but apparently not in the right place.

Where exactly do I need to define the trigger or handler that executes code when the SubMenu is opened?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question. Whether it's the best way to solve my problem, I don't know, but that's how I went about it:

In the ViewModel I created a property "IsSubMenuOpen". In the setter, I query whether the text matches "Logs". If yes, I fill the list with the log files.

```
private bool _isSubMenuOpen;
public bool IsSubMenuOpen
{
    get => _isSubMenuOpen;
    set
    {
        if(Text == "Logs")
        {
            Children.Clear();
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyDir", "*.log"))
            {
                Children.Add(new MyMenuItemViewModel(Path.GetFileName(file)));
            }
        }
        SetProperty(ref _isSubMenuOpen, value);
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow I have created a setter for the property "IsSubMenuopen", and bound my VM property in the value.

```
<Grid>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="{Binding IsSubMenuOpen}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Menu.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyMenuItemViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <local:CustomMenuItemControl/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```